# How to solve typescript errors in mac book with react app while firing in local server?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, types

I am trying to set up a one year old react app in my computer. I am using node 12 version. I want to run the app successfully in my machine and work on it. Can somebody help? I have tried to upgrade the version of react, react-router, react-router-dom and @types/react, @types/react-dom to latest versions.

```
`{
"name": "future-trade",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.89",
"@mui/material": "^5.14.11",
"@types/babel__traverse": "^7.0.8",
"@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
"@types/invariant": "^2.2.34",
"@types/jest": "24.0.17",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
"@types/node": "12.6.9",
"@types/qrcode.react": "^0.8.2",
"@types/react": "^18.2.0",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"@types/react-router": "^5.1.8",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"@types/react-scroll": "^1.5.4",
"@types/react-select": "^3.0.5",
"arc-text": "^1.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"countries-and-timezones": "^1.0.1",
"firebase": "^6.4.0",
"firebase-cli": "^1.2.0",
"firebase-tools": "^7.2.4",
"google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
"jest-diff": "^25.5.0",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.26",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
"qrcode.react": "^0.9.3",
"query-string": "^6.8.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
"react-arc-text-fix": "0.0.0-development",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
"react-bootstrap-timezone-picker": "^2.0.0",
"react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
"react-datasheet": "^1.4.1",
"react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-icons": "^3.7.0",
"react-new-window": "^0.1.2",
"react-phone-code": "0.0.4",
"react-print-components": "^1.0.4",
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1",
"react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
"react-select": "^3.0.8",
"react-timezone": "^2.4.0",
"react-toastify": "^5.3.2",
"react-tooltip": "^4.2.6",
"typescript": "3.2.1"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
"production": \[
"\>0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all",
"ie \>= 9"
\],
"development": \[
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version",
"last 1 ie version"
\]
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.165",
"@types/react-datepicker": "^2.9.2"
}
}
```

```
34173 verbose stack ZlibError: zlib: incorrect data check
34173 verbose stack     at Unzip.write (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:147:22)
34173 verbose stack     at Unpack.write (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:313:19)
34173 verbose stack     at PassThrough.ondata (\_stream_readable.js:718:22)
34173 verbose stack     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:314:20)
34173 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Readable.read (\_stream_readable.js:507:10)
34173 verbose stack     at flow (\_stream_readable.js:1007:34)
34173 verbose stack     at Unpack.pipeOnDrainFunctionResult (\_stream_readable.js:808:7)
34173 verbose stack     at Unpack.emit (events.js:314:20)
34173 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.\<anonymous\> (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:200:36)
34173 verbose stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
34173 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.emit (events.js:314:20)
34173 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.emit (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:414:25)
34173 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.\[flush\] (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:298:12)
34173 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.\[resume\] (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:248:18)
34173 verbose stack     at WriteStream.ondrain (/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:316:67)
34173 verbose stack     at WriteStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
34174 verbose cwd /Users/shravan/Documents/neyaatek/ft-web-app
34175 verbose Darwin 23.0.0
34176 verbose argv "/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node" "/Users/shravan/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/npm" "i"
34177 verbose node v12.22.12
34178 verbose npm  v6.14.18
34179 error code Z_DATA_ERROR
34180 error errno -3
34181 error zlib: incorrect data check
34182 verbose exit \[ -3, true \]`
```